# 'django model' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, django

I get this error when I try to do a query set on the Django model

```py
'AppUser' object is not subscriptable
```

despite it is working normally in a `print` statement but the error only appears when I put it in an `IF` statement

here is my code :

```py
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        print("reached here") #print normaly
        print(AppUser.objects.filter(mobile=instance['mobile']).exists()) #print normally (False)
        if AppUser.objects.filter(mobile=instance['mobile']).exists(): # Raises an Exception
            if instance.playerprofile_set.all().count() > 0:
                player_profile = instance.playerprofile_set.all()[0]
                data['player_profile'] = PlayerProfileSerializer(
                  player_profile).data
                for item in Team.objects.all():
                    if player_profile in item.players.all():
                        data['team'] = TeamSerializer(item).data
                    if item.cap.id == player_profile.id:
                        data['team'] = TeamSerializer(item).data
                    # data["team"] = instance.
        return data
```

**UPDATE**

And here is my `AppUser` class:

```py
class AppUser(models.Model):


    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=33)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=33)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=33)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=33)
    birthdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=33)
    confirm_password = models.CharField(max_length=33)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="uploads", null=True, blank=True)
    main_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    generated_code = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    user_langauge = models.CharField(max_length=33, default="en")
    dark_mode = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.mobile) + " " + str(self.first_name) + " " + str(self.last_name)
```

so calling `AppUser.objects.filter()` should return a queryset or empty query set, and when adding `exists()` should return a `True` or

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of count, use [`exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists):

```
if AppUser.objects.filter(mobile=instance['mobile']).exists():
   if instance.playerprofile_set.exists():
            player_profile = instance.playerprofile_set.first()
```

Because it is very efficient in contrast to `count()` and runs a very small query.

To your original problem, it is not possible to guess what is wrong from the sample code, specially when print works, `if` not.

### Update

I think the error should be with this code:

```
instance['mobile']
```

Here instance should be an object, so `instance.mobile` or `data['mobile']` should work.

Comment: Changed to `exists()` ,, same error still and I have added some more info in the question

Comment: Can you add the full error stacktrace please?

Comment: Yes it was the error causing , i used it to make sure that object is not created , but it caused the problem

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 def to_representation(self, instance):
            data = super().to_representation(instance)
            print("reached here") #print normaly
            print(AppUser.objects.filter(mobile=instance['mobile']).count() > 0) #print normally (False)
            if AppUser:
              AppUser.objects.filter(mobile=instance['mobile']).count() > 0
              if instance.playerprofile_set.all().count() > 0:
                    player_profile = instance.playerprofile_set.all()[0]
                    data['player_profile'] = PlayerProfileSerializer(
                      player_profile).data
                    for item in Team.objects.all():
                        if player_profile in item.players.all():
                            data['team'] = TeamSerializer(item).data
                        if item.cap.id == player_profile.id:
                            data['team'] = TeamSerializer(item).data
                        # data["team"] = instance.
            return data
```

Comment: Badly it gave the same result